# Powers of matrices equality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

let $A$ be a $3$ by $3$ matrix with two eigenvalues $\lambda _1, \lambda _2$ such that $\lambda _1$ has algebraic multiplicity $2$ and $\lambda _2$ has multiplicity $1$.

I want to prove that $(A-\lambda _1I)^{n+2}=(\lambda _2-\lambda _1)^n(A-\lambda _1I)^2$.

As a hint I'm given
$$A-\lambda _2I=A-\lambda _1I-(\lambda _2-\lambda _1)I$$
$$(A-\lambda _1)^2(A-\lambda _2)=0$$

How can I use the above to prove that $$(A-\lambda _1I)^{n+2}=(\lambda _2-\lambda _1)^n(A-\lambda _1I)^2 \text{for all }n\in \mathbb N?$$

I have tried powering $A-\lambda _2I=A-\lambda _1I-(\lambda _2-\lambda _1)I$ but it didn't help at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that $(A-\lambda_1I)$ and $(A-\lambda_2I)$ commute and use the binomial formula.

We have by the binomial formula
$$(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)^nI=((A-\lambda_1I)-(A-\lambda_2I))^{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}(A-\lambda_1I)^{n-k}(-1)^k(A-\lambda_2I)^k\\=(A-\lambda_1I)^{n}+(-1)^{n-1}n(A-\lambda_1I)(A-\lambda_2I)^{n-1}+(-1)^n(A-\lambda_2I)^n$$
Now multiply this equality by $(A-\lambda_1I)^2$.

Comment: Should I be computing $((A-\lambda _1I)+(A-\lambda _2I))^n?$

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Try using induction on $n$, noting that $$(A - \lambda_1 I)^{n+1+2} = (A - \lambda_1 I)^{n+2}(A - \lambda_2 I + (\lambda_2 - \lambda_1) I)$$